# Javascript Add object to Date via prototype

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an object property to Date object in JS by using the `getTime()` functionality.

```
 Date.prototype.stdDate={
         Hour:Math.ceil(getTime()/(1000 * 3600)),
         Day:Math.ceil(getTime()/(1000 * 3600 * 24)),
         Week:Math.ceil(getTime()/(1000*3600*24*7)),
         Year:Math.ceil(getTime()/(1000*3600*24*365.242))
    }
```

but I keep on receiving this error while testing on my chrome console :

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: getTime is not defined
```

I understand that the reason is that the scope in the function cannot access getTime() that is inside Date, and when looking for it in the global and local context without finding, it is eventually throwing that error.

I even tried it with `this` ! `this.getTime()`

still: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

you guys can still try it on the console

So my question is how to do it in the right way guys ?

Comment: use getTime on a date object. var d = new Date; d.getTime()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to *call* `getDate` as the moment you're adding that to the prototype. Instead, you want to call it later, when the property is accessed.

You have two options: Methods, or properties with "getters". In your case, I'm thinking just one method:

```
Date.prototype.stdDate = function(part) {
    switch (String(part).toLowerCase()) {
        case "hour":
            return Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000 * 3600));
        case "day":
            return Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000 * 3600 * 24));
        case "week":
            return Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000*3600*24*7));
        case "year":
            return Math.ceil(getTime()/(1000*3600*24*365.242));
        default:
            // What you think appropriate
    }
};
```

Note that there I'm defining just a *single* function, `stdDate`, which accepts a string argument:

```
var hour = dt.stdDate("hour");
```

That's because if we made `stdDate` refer to an object and put methods on the object, `this` wouldn't refer to the date anymore. (There are ways around it, but they're more cumbersome than is probably warranted here.)

On ES5-enabled engines, it would be possible (but probably more trouble than it's worth) to make `dt.stdDate.Hour` and such work:

```
// On the prototype, define a property called `stdDate` that has a getter
Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, "stdDate", {
    get: function() {
        // This is the getter: Create an object with properties for
        // Hour, Day, and such which have getters. The getters are
        // "bound" to `this` using `Function#bind`:
        var stdDate = {};
        Object.defineProperties(stdDate, {
            Hour:  {
                read: function() {
                    return Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000 * 3600));
                }.bind(this),
            },
            Day: {
                read: function() {
                    return Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000 * 3600 * 24));
                }.bind(this),
            },
            Week: {
                read: function() {
                    return Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000*3600*24*7));
                }.bind(this),
            },
            Year: {
                read: function() {
                    return Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000*3600*24*365.242));
                }.bind(this)
            }
        });

        // Now, redefine the `stdDate` property on this specific instance
        Object.defineProperty(this, "stdDate", {
            value: stdDate
        });

        // And return it
        return stdDate;
    }
});
```

*(You'll probably have to tinker with that to get it working perfectly; I'm dashing out and can't debug it right now. But the idea is there.)*

That's ***really convoluted*** and probably not a good idea, but if the API `dt.stdDate.Hour` was really important to you, well, it's *possible*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was wondering in case if I do Date.stdDate=function() instead of Date.prototype.stdDate=function() would it change something ?

Comment: @user3135757: Yes, that would be compoletely different. Instead of adding the property to the prototype of all `Date` instances, you'd be adding it to the `Date` function; instances wouldn't have access to it (except via `Date.stdDate`).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `this.getTime()` to call the `.getTime()` method of the object it's running on:

```
Date.prototype.stdDate={
         Hour:Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000 * 3600)),
         Day:Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000 * 3600 * 24)),
         Week:Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000*3600*24*7)),
         Year:Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000*3600*24*365.242))
    }
```

EDIT:

Oh, and you need to define it as a function...

```
Date.prototype.stdDate= function() {return{
         Hour:Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000 * 3600)),
         Day:Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000 * 3600 * 24)),
         Week:Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000*3600*24*7)),
         Year:Math.ceil(this.getTime()/(1000*3600*24*365.242))
    }}
```

Comment: I tried already : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionmessage: "undefined is not a function"

Comment: Fixed. You need to define it as a function.

Comment: Thanks I was wondering will it change something in case if you use Date.stdDate instead of Date.prototype.stdDate

Comment: Yes, it will change it. Then it would be a static property of `Date`, not a prototype property available on `Date` instances.